# How to remove WooCommerce order status?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, themes

I would like to modify a function contained in woocommerce. This is my edited function (`woocommerce/includes/wc-order-functions.php`):

```
function wc_get_order_statuses() {
    $order_statuses = array(
        'wc-pending'    => _x( 'Pending Payment', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' ),
        /*'wc-processing' => _x( 'Processing', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' ),*/
        'wc-on-hold'    => _x( 'On Hold', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' ),
        'wc-completed'  => _x( 'Completed', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' ),
        'wc-cancelled'  => _x( 'Cancelled', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' ),
        'wc-refunded'   => _x( 'Refunded', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' ),
        'wc-failed'     => _x( 'Failed', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' ),
    );
    return apply_filters( 'wc_order_statuses', $order_statuses );
}
```

I tried to load a new function within the `function.php` file in the child theme, but does not seem to work.

what I want to achieve is to eliminate the order item "Processing" from the status menu. I also tried with css but those do not support

```
select option[value="wc-processing"] {display: none !important;}
```

Comment: The filter `wc_order_statuses` is there so that you can modify the `$order_status` array with your own custom values. What are you adding to `functions.php`?

Comment: hi edit the code right this 'if ( ! function_exists( 'wc_get_order_statuses' ) ) :
   function wc_get_order_statuses() {'

Comment: Can you edit your question to explain what you are trying to add to `wc_get_order_statuses()`?  It is *not* a pluggable function, so you cannot override it, you must filter the result. I can propose something once I know what you are attempting.

Comment: @helgatheviking i need to remove the processing status from order status menù, please help me I lost hope  XD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use filters. Once upon a time, I wrote what I think is a good tutorial explaining [WordPress filters](https://www.kathyisawesome.com/wordpress-filters-fundamentals/)

In this case, the end result would be:

```
function so_39252649_remove_processing_status( $statuses ){
    if( isset( $statuses['wc-processing'] ) ){
        unset( $statuses['wc-processing'] );
    }
    return $statuses;
}
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'so_39252649_remove_processing_status' );
```

Keep in mind, that the processing status is the default status when an order is created, so you may have to make other changes to compensate for it's removal.

Comment: i love you! you can also order the states? I wish that the state failed to appear first in the menu. in the meantime I'm studying your article!

Comment: If this is the answer, please check the green checkmark to "accept" it. You can do any kind of array manipulation to the `$statuses` array that you would like. You can also completely define your own array.

Comment: how can i set the order? @helgatheviking

Comment: This is a new question, but as I said, you can define a new `$statuses` array and return that.

Comment: So, when a order is paid, goes directly to completed?