# Hiding order status in My Account recent orders list page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

In WooCommerce, I have a Woocommerce site and on the customer's recent orders page, there is a table with order details on this example link: `https://example.com/my-account/view-order/`

I would like to completely hide order status from the table if possible.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39252649/how-to-remove-woocommerce-order-status
This ticket may help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated:**

Just use this custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_columns`** filter hook:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_columns', 'custom_removing_order_status', 10, 1);

function custom_removing_order_status( $order ){
    unset($order['order-status']);
    return $order;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

No need of editing woocommerce templates. **This code is tested and works**.

Comment: Works great! Tested it on WooCommerce 5.9.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize woocommerce/templates/myaccount/my-orders.php template to your theme file.

You will see a variable named "$my_orders_columns". Just remove order-status column from there.

Also, remove it from "$customer_orders" variable, so that it will not unnecessary query to get status.